# Start service remote by http request

Tags: http, authentication, debian, systemd

I hava a systemd service "myservice" running as user www-data. I want to start/stop/restart this service by a http request. The problem is, that I get an error because of missing authentication:

> Failed to restart myservice.service: Interactive authentication required.
>   See system logs and 'systemctl status myservice.service' for details.

First I request a php script, calling restartService.sh:

```
$exec_command = "../restartService.sh";
```

restartService.sh is only one command:

```
systemctl restart myservice.service
```

Owner and group of restartService.sh are ww-data:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data  www-data    41 Aug 24 12:42 restartService.sh
```

Any suggestions for solutions?

Comment: Take a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/841099/systemd-grant-an-unprivileged-user-permission-to-alter-one-specific-service or the linked questions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password) configuration to give the `www-data` user permission to run `systemctl restart yourservice` without giving it permission to run any other commands as root.